# How to resize matrix like image in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, resize

How to resize a matrix in python, say `np.random.randn(100,100)`, to shape [50,50]? I hope to get interpolation like what we expect for image resize, like `cv2.imresize`. But I don't find some decent way to do for matrix.

I think `np.resize` does't serve this purpose for it do no interpolation to keep the new matrix "looks" like the old one, using the `plt.matshow()`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = np.random.randn(100,100)

# how to do?
b = resize(a, ) # something like this 


plt.matshow(a)
plt.matshow(b)
plt.show()

--> a and b looks quite like but with different size
```

Comment: Kind of depends on how you want to deal with downsampling. Average? take every other pixel? But really, you could just use `cv2.resize` on the matrix. You might have to convert it to an image first though.

Comment: `numpy` does not have this kind of `resize`, at least not in the basic operations like `resize` and `reshape`.  You require some sort of interpolation or fancier mapping.  Image processing packages implement this.  The closest is a crude sampling like `b[::2, ::2]`.

Comment: you could use `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform(a, np.diag((2,2)), output_shape=(50,50))`

Comment: I advise using [resize](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#resize) function from [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org/).

Comment: Thanks guys. After trying to find a standard implementation with no result, I think I need to write it by myself. It might still be quite fast with matrix implementation and the method is quite similar to bilinear interpolation.